# Override tab bar changing its height

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I tried to search before but I could not find any solution to my question.
I want to change the height of the TabBar doing an override of the old TabBar.
I know that one possible solution is to create a UIViewController subclass and start from scratch or sottoclassare UITabBar but I wanted to try it this way and I can not understand why not work.

```
import UIKit

class NewTabBarController: UITabBarController {

let newTabBar : UITabBar = {

    let tmpView = UITabBar.init()
    tmpView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    tmpView.accessibilityLabel = "Nuova Tab Bar"
    tmpView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return tmpView

}()

override var tabBar: UITabBar{


    return self.newTabBar

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

            self.view.addSubview(newTabBar)
    self.newTabBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    self.newTabBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    self.newTabBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    self.newTabBar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

I tried various solutions. 
Using the frame, the constraint but none of these worked.
With constraints I obtain this error

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot modify constraints for
UITabBar managed by a controller'
```

Using frame instead :

```
var newTabBar : UITabBar = {

    let tmpView = UITabBar.init()
    tmpView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    tmpView.accessibilityLabel = "New Bar"
    return tmpView

}()

override var tabBar: UITabBar{


    return self.newTabBar

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.newTabBar.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - 110, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 110)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

it doesn't appear.
If I add my newTabBar as subview, it will appear but the first doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.tested in `Swift 3`

```
let CustomTabBarHeight = 100 // Set your custom tabBar height here

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    var customTabFrame = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame
    customTabFrame?.size.height = CGFloat(CustomTabBarHeight)
    customTabFrame?.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - CGFloat(CustomTabBarHeight)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame = customTabFrame!
    tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = .black
    tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = .white
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works for me too but i'm asking : "Why I cannot use override getter for do that?" .  In my opinion it should be correct because I'm overriding a super's properties.